# Transactional emails if conditions discrepancy

Tags: email-templates, transactional

Trying to set different text for registered and guest customers order confirmation email (using single template, not sure why Magento has two different settings for this?) I've come across that `{{if order.getCustomerIsGuest()}}` always evaluates to true rendering `{{else}}` useless

I worked it around by using `{{if order.getCustomerGroupId()}}` but hoping someone can shed some light what can be culprit of this and to avoid other's pitfalls trying to implement this logic the same way as I originally did

Comment: Just wondering what the point of that is - why not just make two templates and apply one to be sent to guests in the admin config?

Comment: @McNab thing is templates are exactly the same, with just one difference about tracking order info hence guest customers don't have accounts

Comment: Fair enough, I know what you mean - seems like unneccessary duplication. The only reason I mention it is because the Magento default Order confirmation and Guest Order confirmations themselves are also virtually identical....and if further changes are required later on it starts making less and less sense to have them running through the same template with conditional statements.

Comment: @McNab agreed, if that will be the case I'll probably separate them back, but main question here why obvious getCustomerIsGuest() which can be only 1 or 0 always evaluates to true

Comment: How did you solve the issue? Post an answer here, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand why your code doesn't work. See `Varien_Filter_Template::ifDirective()`: It compares `'0'` or `'1'` to `''`, which will both return `false`.

What I don't understand is why the same construct with `customer_group_id` does work. The only thing I can think of is that `customer_group_id` is filled with `NULL` in `sales_flat_order` table (which it isn't in my installation).

The only 2 simple solutions (implementation in < 1h) I can think of:

- Extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and add a function called `getCustomerIsGuest` that returns `false` or `true` instead of `'0'` or `'1'`
- Extend `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter` and replace the function `ifDirective` so it will treat `'0'` as `false`

Comment: To be clear: the `customer_group_id` workaround you describe doesn't work in my environment.

Comment: Yes, `customer_group_id` is stored as 0 here for guest customers as well. I'll take a deeper look and report back. Thanks for the insight!